# mongoose sort by dates from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I have a `Chat` model which has a `messages` array which holds `Message`s. Each `Message` has both a `dateSent` property and a `dateViewed` property. The `Message` items are *embedded*, not *referenced*.

How can I sort `Chat`s by most recent *not viewed* `Message` (ie, empty `dateViewed`) first and then by `dateSent`? (think Facebook Messenger behavior...)

This is what I've tried so far (note that `Chat` also has a `users` array):

```
Chat.find({users._id: userId}).sort({messages.dateViewed: -1, messages.dateSent: -1}).exec(function(err, chats){
    // handle err
    // handle no docs found
    // handle docs found
});
```

The above does not seem to work, as the `Chat`s come out in a different order (the same as without `sort()`). Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** The suggested answer didn't help me because I don't want to sort the `Message` objects in the `message` array, but rather sort the `Chats` resulting from the query, by the dates in the `Message` object they hold in a `messages` array.

Comment: I'm not sure how `messages.dateViewd: -1` is interpreted, I would suggest  at least adding quotes, just to be sure everything's fine there :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Yes, I've changed it to `{"messages.dateViewed": -1, "messages.dateSent": -1}`, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb: sort documents by array objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315658/mongodb-sort-documents-by-array-objects)

Comment: Another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889240/mongodb-sort-documents-by-array-elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort the array in the document with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889780/sort-the-array-in-the-document-with-mongodb)

Comment: @Tom The problem with peoples "possible duplicate" selection is that they rarely really look to see that the answer actually addresses the problem. For instance the answer I gave on [Sort the array in the document with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889780/sort-the-array-in-the-document-with-mongodb) is done in realization that [Mongodb: sort documents by array objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315658/mongodb-sort-documents-by-array-objects) does not actually answer the question asked, thought it will regularly come up in a search.

Comment: The other thing you may be asking is how to search by the "min" or "max" value from within the array on the results. That is answered here: [sort by embedded object value in Mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592200/sort-by-embedded-object-value-in-mongodb/33592563#33592563)

Answer (score 1):

The Aggregation pipeline should be used in order to achieve the required sort.

chats/messages:

```
> db.chats.find()
{ "_id" : "c1", "messages" : [ { "_id" : "m1_1", "dv" : -1, "ds" : 9000 }, { "_id" : "m1_2", "dv" : 8010, "ds" : 8000 } ] }
{ "_id" : "c2", "messages" : [ { "_id" : "m2_1", "dv" : -1, "ds" : 11000 } ] }
{ "_id" : "c3", "messages" : [ { "_id" : "m3_1", "dv" : -1, "ds" : 700 }, { "_id" : "m3_2", "dv" : 7010, "ds" : 7000 } ] }
```

The code to sort the data by the give criteria:

```
db.chats.aggregate([
{ $unwind: '$messages' },
{ $addFields: { 
        ts: { 
            $cond: [ 
                { $eq: ['$messages.dv', -1 ] }, 
                '$messages.ds', 
                '$messages.dv']
        }
    }
}, 
{ 
    $sort: { 'ts': -1 }
}, 
{     
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        ts: { $max: '$ts'},
        messages: { $push: '$messages' }     
    }
}, 
{ 
    $sort: {ts: -1}
}]);
```

The results:

```
{ "_id" : "c2", "ts" : 11000, "messages" : [ { "_id" : "m2_1", "dv" : -1, "ds" : 11000 } ] }
{ "_id" : "c1", "ts" : 9000, "messages" : [ { "_id" : "m1_1", "dv" : -1, "ds" : 9000 }, { "_id" : "m1_2", "dv" : 8010, "ds" : 8000 } ] }
{ "_id" : "c3", "ts" : 7010, "messages" : [ { "_id" : "m3_2", "dv" : 7010, "ds" : 7000 }, { "_id" : "m3_1", "dv" : -1, "ds" : 700 } ] }
```